# How to choose functions for proofs (proving linear functional)

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:** Let $F$ be a field and let $0 \neq a \in F$. Let $\alpha : F[X] \to F$ be defined by $\alpha : p(x) \mapsto p(a)- p(0)$. Is $\alpha$ a linear functional?

I have done similar problems and know how to show linear functional but I do not know how to choose the functions to use... So in order to show that $L(f+g)=L(f)+L(g)$ for this question what do I use for f and g?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use any example for $f$ and $g$ other than saying $f(x),g(x) \in F[x]$. Then, calculate $\alpha(f+g)$ and $\alpha(f)+\alpha(g)$ and see if you get the same expression:

$$\alpha(f+g)=(f+g)(a)-(f+g)(0)=f(a)+g(a)-f(0)-g(0)$$
$$\alpha(f)+\alpha(g)=f(a)-f(0)+g(a)-g(0)$$

Now, using the commutative property of addition that rings have, we get $\alpha(f+g)=\alpha(f)+\alpha(g)$ for all $f, g \in F[x]$.

Now, if you can also prove $\alpha(c\cdot f)=c\cdot\alpha(f)$ using a generic $f(x) \in F[x]$, you will have proven that $\alpha$ is a linear functional. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As for vector spaces and the like, choose $f, g \in F[X]$ and just use that. You should also choose a scalar $k$ from this field to show linearity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take two polynomials $p$ and $q$, then $\alpha(p+q)=(p+q)(a)-(p+q)(0)=p(a)+q(a)-(p(0)+q(0))=p(a)-p(0)+q(a)-q(0)=\alpha(p)+\alpha(q)$